# How to get validation constraints of ApplicationRecord model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a class that looks like:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  validates :field, presence: true,
                    inclusion:{
                      in: %w[foo bar baz bla]
                    }
end
```

I need a method that returns the `inclusion` part of the `validation` for the `field` column. e.g.:

```
data = Account.validations_for(:field) # Or some similar magick method
data[:inclusion][:in] # => ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bla']
```

Does something similar exist? If it was in an `enum` it could be simple, but I can't find the way to do it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do want to do this the fun Rails way:

```
Account.validators_on(:field).detect { |validator| validator.is_a? ActiveModel::Validations::InclusionValidator }.options[:in]
```

That'll return you an array of your fields.

Otherwise, while this isn't the black magic you're looking for, I'd adjust to the following to make this nice and flexible:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  FIELD_OPTIONS = %w[foo bar baz bla].freeze

  validates :field, presence: true,
                    inclusion:{
                      in: FIELD_OPTIONS
                    }
```

Then you've got nice simple access via `Account::FIELD_OPTIONS`.

Either any use? Let me know how they suit / if you have any questions.

Comment: The second answer is just perfect. How did you arrived to it? I'm asking as it feels like I was searching for the wrong keywords on search engines. I'm always amazed as how intuitive Rails is, checking my original post, the answer seems very similar.

Comment: Did a little digging in `pry` with `ls -G` :) Great way to see what's in there. Also had a use case to hand to test it on, which helped. Glad it's useful - shout if you have any other questions.